# Hard disk decryption, forgotten key

Tags: encryption

I am using ubuntu14.04. During installation, I encrypted my hard disk. Now, I forgot my key and I have a lot of important data on my system that I want to recover. Is there a way to change my pass-phrase or remove it or may be any other way to backup my data.

Comment: **Can you please clarify:** Do you still have access to the data, and want to find out the key? .. OR, as already answered by **@Thomas W.**, were you operating with NO backup and NO recorded key?

Answer (score 7):

If you do not have the original key that you used to encrypt the data, you are not going to be able to decrypt the data and recover  o.

The whole idea of disk encryption is that if you don't have the key, you can't just easily 'recover the data' from the disk or partition. If there were such a way to easily access the data, it would defeat the point of disk encryption, which is to prevent others who do not have the key from easily decrypting the data.

Unfortunately, that concept has a flaw: if *you* were the one that set up the key, and forgot the key, you no longer have a way to access the data.  That key is required to decrypt the data, and without it there is no way to decrypt the data to recover it.